# Angular ng-repeat to list all users with their notes

Tags: angularjs, list, angularjs-ng-repeat

My application returns a list of users and then when you click on a user, it returns the user's notes via JSON (Example below). The problem I have is that some customers have multiple notes associated with them.

Is their a way to use ng-repeat to list customer's name with their notes?

I am able to get Customers name using:

```
<tr ng-repeat="users in userList">
    <td>{{users.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

However, I am not able to get the user's notes using `users.userNotes.note_string`.

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Test Name",
   "userNotes": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "note_string": "Test Note String 1",
         "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Name",
            "userNotes": []
         }
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "note_string": "Test Note String 2",
         "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Name",
            "userNotes": []
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like userNotes is an array, so you won't be able to directly retrieve "note_string" without an index of some sort. *Edit: or another repeat as Emil mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use another repeat, e.g.

```
<tr ng-repeat="users in userList">
    <td>{{users.id}}</td>
    <td><p ng-repeat="note in users.userNotes">{{note.note_string}}</p></td>
</tr>
```